# Why IntelliJ shows "Duplicated code fragment (x lines long)" warning?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am new in IntelliJ IDEA and use a line as shown below:

```
List<UUID> employeeUuidList = employeeService.findAllEmployeesByMainUuid(request.getMainUuid());
```

Interestingly, it gives "*Duplicated code fragment (19 lines long)*" error. I have a look at on the web, there are some suggestion to suppress this warning, but I want to understand the main cause of this warning and fix it by code side without changing setting.

It is also ok if you give suggestion for suppressing this warning.

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. Error messages are shown, printed, logged, etc. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: IntelliJ watch at all files in your project, so the duplicated code is probably in another file. It is misleading since one can think the duplicated code is within the current file we edit. However by looking at the duplicated code window, one can look at the file paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Duplicated code fragment (19 lines long)

This is neither a error nor a serious warning. It is just a highlight from intelliJ that those 19 lines are repeated elsewhere.

You could probably refactor the code by extracting those duplicate lines to a common method.

If you want to disable it completely (I don't recommend though), goto `preferences > Editor > Duplicates` or simply search `duplicate` in the `preferences` and there you can enable/disable this feature for a language.

Attached screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Duplicated code fragment" is the warning triggered by the inspection: *General | Duplicated code fragment*. To see the duplicates you may press "Alt+Enter" (in the line where the warning appears) and select the "Show all duplicates like this":
[image]